# Want to learn Blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I am completely new to this technology ..i wanted to learn blockchain and starting with doublespending, POW, consensus,miners,mining everything i am not able to relate things and get clear with the exact concept...can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Best resource is the book "Mastering Bitcoin" by Andreas Antonopoulos. You can find it online at https://bitcoinbook.info. You can download it for free on github. The book explains everything in a structured and easy-to-process way.